# Android Native Module: How to go back to React Native from native Android Activity?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-bridge

I implemented android native bridge module in which I call native **SampleActivity** from React Native.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

By pressing the physical back button or calling finish() from this **SampleActivity** makes whole app quit instead of going back to original react native activity.
How to go back to react native?

Similar Issues:

1. https://www.techup.co.in/call-native-android-activity-from-react-native/
2. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17250